# Need to delete first N lines of grep result files

Tags: linux, wordpress, bash, sed, grep

I'm trying to get rid of a hacker issue on some of my wordpress installs.

This guy puts 9 lines of code in the head of multiple files on my server... I'm trying to use grep and sed to solve this.

Im trying:

```
grep -r -l  "//360cdn.win/c.css" | xargs -0 sed -e '1,9d' < {}
```

But nothing is happening, if I remove `-0 from`xargs`, the result of the files found are clean, but they are not overwriting the origin file with the`sed` result, can anyone help me with that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `--null` option in `grep` command to output a NUL byte or `\0` after each filename in the `grep` output. Also use `-i.bak` in `sed` for inline editing of each file:

```
grep -lR --null '//360cdn.win/c\.css' . | xargs -0 sed -i.bak '1,9d'
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!! Im trying to solve this for the last 4 hours!! =D

Comment: @RenanCorrêaPinto the way to say "thank you " on [so] is by *accepting* (and/or *upvoting*) an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with iterating over the files directly¹?

And you might want to add the `-i` flat to *sed* so that files are edited *i*n-place

```
grep -r -l  "//360cdn.win/c.css" | while read f
do
   sed -e '1,9d' -i "${f}"
done
```

¹ well, you might get problems if your files contain newlines and the like.
but then...if your website contains files with newlines, you probably have other problems anyhow...